# Implementing a model for 'Flash Fill'

Tags: machine-learning

MS Excel (since 2013) offers a [Flash Fill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzbsMguaKkk&feature=youtu.be&t=52s) feature that learns how you want to transform columns in your spread sheet based on training data for some rows and then applies this transformation on all rows.

I tried to implement such a feature myself for using genetic programming, but even for simple transformations the learning process took quite long. (It was based on automatic generation of regular expressions)

What other models (than genetic programming of regular expressions) could I try to implement such an automatic learning of transformations?

PS: if it works, I'm planing to build a LibreOffice plugin ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect flash fill has a hardcoded list of things to try : initial letter matches, etc.

Consider the following list:

```
man M
woman W
man M
woman W
man 
man 
man 
man 
woman
```

Flash fill works here and correctly fills in 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'W' for the remaining cells.

But try changing the W's to w's (lowercase), and flashfill fails.   If it uses any kind of machine learning, the M's and W's would just be arbitrary tokens, and it wouldn't care what they were.  But the fact that it doesn't work when some are uppercase and some are lower tells us it manually tries a list of pre-defined transformations.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  While this response does help illuminate the problem posed in the question, it does not help answer "What other models (than genetic programming of regular expressions) could I try to implement such an automatic learning of transformations?"